# CartonCloud Search API filtration by Sales Order Created Date

Tags: logistics

I'm trying to integrate CartonCloud with my system and I'm trying to use the [Sales Order API - Search API](https://api-docs.cartoncloud.com/#search-outbound-orders) as mentioned in their documentation. The issue is I cannot find a field for Sales Order Created Date to filter orders by it, but the UI where I could view Sales Orders has a column called "Added Date".

I understand the condition application of the search API as mentioned in their documents but I cannot find a field that maps to "Added Date" which allows me to use it in the filter. It would be a big help if anyone could share some information about this. Thanks